# How to add siteCommand in camel-ftp URL?

Tags: apache-camel, mainframe

I am trying to upload a file from my local directory to IBM mainframe FTPS server, which needs SITE commands to set the record length.
I need to include the siteCOmmand as part of the URL.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Camel FTP documentation
http://camel.apache.org/ftp2

And notice there is a siteCommand option.
If there is no examples / more details on the web pages, then check the unit tests of the camel component to find examples

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=camel.git;a=tree;f=components/camel-ftp/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/file/remote;h=d29b29b071802ae56c52f36a099213d1a0cc9b62;hb=HEAD

In that link you can find unit tests with the site command